# How to specify an initial value for `foldr` when using `Ordering` to compare values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fold

I am doing the exercise 10.10 in *Haskell Programming From First Principles* , the question is to write a `myMaximumBy` function using `foldr`:

```
myMaximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
myMaximumBy = undefined
```

I am trying to do this:

```
myMaximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
myMaximumBy f = foldr (\x y -> if f x y == LT then y else x) INIT_VAL
```

But I do not know how to specify an initial value `INIT_VAL` for this expression. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I’m a little surprised the book asks you to write such a function, given that it’s partial—it clearly can’t produce a value given an empty list. You could handle the empty list case explicitly, or you could use `foldr1`, but I can’t guess what the “intended” solution would be.

Comment: Well, no.  That type signature is fundamentally incorrect.  You cannot find a base case because it's impossible.

Comment: @Carl it's as incorrect as that of `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first item of the list as your start case, and then process the rest of the list:

```
myMaximumBy _ [] = error "Empty list"
myMaximumBy f (v:vs) = foldr (\x y -> if f x y == LT then y else x) v vs
```